# Is it possible to include another aspx files to a aspx that you are working on inside SharePoint Designer 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is it possible? How do I do it inside SharePoint Designer 2007 if it is possible?

(Something like the PHP `include()` function)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [page viewer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/page-viewer-web-part-HA010024045.aspx) webpart to include another aspx or another webpage in your page. It works like an IFRAME in html